# vertical line with Latex table

Tags: latex

I am trying to use latex to generate table.
The following table is what I get currently.

[image: my latex table]

```
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc}
    \toprule   
    \multirow{3}{*}{Test Sequence} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Thomas et al.} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Pan et al.} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Liu et al.} \\
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{VTM-5.0} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{VTM-6.0} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{VTM-10.0} \\
    &
    BDBR(\%) & $\Delta{T}$(\%) & 
    BDBR(\%) & $\Delta{T}$(\%) &
    BDBR(\%) & $\Delta{T}$(\%) \\
    \hline
    \multirow{1}{*}{Class A} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{label-1} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{label-2} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{label-3} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{label-4} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{label-5} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{label-6} \\
    4096$\times2160$ \\
    \hline
    Average & itemB & itemC & itemD & itemE & itemF & itemG \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I use multirow to center the label, but this way will  make the vertical line disappear.
How do I modify my code to fullfill the vertical line?

I want to fullfill the discontinuous vertical line

Comment: Please have a look at the booktabs documentation -- if you want a professional looking table, don't use vertical lines

Comment: Sounds like a question you should ask in the LaTeX sister page ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use vertical lines in tables, this does not look very professional.

If you insist on such a layout, you could use `m` columns, which will have a fixed width and automatically centre the content vertically:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering}m{2.2cm}|
  >{\centering}m{1.5cm}
  >{\centering}m{1.5cm}|
  >{\centering}m{1.5cm}
  >{\centering}m{1.5cm}|
  >{\centering}m{1.5cm}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}
}
    \toprule   
    \multirow{3}{*}{Test Sequence} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Thomas et al.} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Pan et al.} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Liu et al.} \\
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{VTM-5.0} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{VTM-6.0} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{VTM-10.0} \\
    &
    BDBR(\%) & $\Delta{T}$(\%) & 
    BDBR(\%) & $\Delta{T}$(\%) &
    BDBR(\%) & $\Delta{T}$(\%) \\
    \hline
    Class A 4096$\times2160$ & 
    label-1 & 
    label-2 & 
    label-3 & 
    label-4 & 
    label-5 & 
    label-6 \\
    \hline
    Average & itemB & itemC & itemD & itemE & itemF & itemG \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]